# Magento Admin: Display 404 page on login to admin in content section

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, 404-page

What is working: All admin and its functionality is working and 404 error page display in content section only once though top menu always display.

Error Produce: When i login to admin, it display 404 page in central content section Only. Version : 1.9.0.1

I have no problem to access and working in admin but this error is awkward so would be great if fixed.

Comment: Do you use restricted admin accounts? What is the URL of the page where you see 404 ? What is the configured starup page (in System > Configuration > Admin)?

Comment: I have created sub-admins but this issue is for main admin. Startup page is dashboard (in System > Configuration > Admin) and i had checked that. What could be reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you use any admin restricted extension?

you have to check acl permission for 404 page.

also check in particular controller(according 404 page controller action) file have below code

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('modulename/controlleraction');
}
```

Comment: yes i have used acl extension and do i need to check in that extension controller ?

Comment: do not need to check in your extension controller you need to check in your custom module extension have protected function _isAllowed() ? if already there then check ('modulename/controlleraction') is it proper?